# Qt - Error when starting 5 threads from object array

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a application in Qt as my semester project. The topic is "Problem of dining philosophers". Now I have a problem and I don't really know how to solve it. The problem is: I have an array of objects called `filozofowie` (philisophers) and it contains objects of class `filozof` (philosopher). Class philospher is derived from class Thread. When I am trying to start threads from array in for loop, it's starting four of them and then error occurs.
Here's the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqkdK.png

Here's the code:

Filozof.h

```cpp
#ifndef FILOZOF_H
#define FILOZOF_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

class Filozof : public QThread
{
    public:
    Filozof();
    void run();
    QString name;
    QLabel *stan;
};

#endif
```

Mainclass.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINCLASS_H
#define MAINCLASS_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Filozof.h"

class MainClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainClass(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~MainClass();
    Ui::MainClassClass ui;
    Filozof filozofowie[4];
    QSystemSemaphore *kelner;

public slots: 
    void startSimulation();
    void stopSimulation();
};

#endif // MAINCLASS_H
```

Part of `mainclass.cpp`

```cpp
void MainClass::startSimulation() 
{
    this->kelner = new QSystemSemaphore("kelner", 4, QSystemSemaphore::Create);
    ui.textEdit->append("[" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + "] Start      symulacji");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        filozofowie[i].start();
        if(filozofowie[i].isRunning())
        {
           ui.textEdit->append("[" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + "] Watek filozofa " + QString::number(i) + " wystartowal");
        }else{
           ui.textEdit->append("[" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + "] Blad podczas tworzenia watku filozofa " + QString::number(i));
       }
   }

    ui.buttonStart->setEnabled(false);
    ui.buttonStop->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Please don't mind the text in append, those are messages in Polish.

Comment: Please write out the error in the question, questions should be self-contained and not depend on other websites.

Comment: @luketorjussen: please read the homework tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you have problem here:

```
Filozof filozofowie[4];
```

Indexes are 0..3, but here you have 0..4:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Also, your "if isRunning" is a bit funny. You maybe should connect the started signal, or use the waitForStarted method.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I've already found the solution. It was really obvious, but I am a bit sick (flu or something) and headache does not help. Thank you also for the second part of response. I am new to QT so I don't know everything, but for sure it will help :-).